# Unusual empty error dialogue on edit review

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, error-message

Reviewing some edits this morning and I got this:

[image]

I'm not aware that I did anything I don't normally do, and not sure what this is trying to indicate to me.

Suggested edit was on this, [How can I secure a JSP page after adding it to my hosting and making it live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974400/how-can-i-secure-a-jsp-page-after-adding-it-to-my-hosting-and-making-it-live/19974527#19974527), and Community diamond was rejecting, perhaps at around the same time.

When I go back to the page, it just looks like the normal aftermath of a completed review. I had done several edits previously without seeing it. This was the initial presentation of the review, not after I'd done something.

Comment: That's not an image, it's an empty error dialog. It *should* pop up with some message when you do something you shouldn't do or something fails.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce, do you still get it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, Thanks, I've updated with a little more. No, when I go back to the page, it just looks like the normal aftermath of a completed review. I had done several edits previously without seeing it. This was the initial presentation of the review, not after I'd done something.

Comment: Yeah, [here is direct link to the suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3355531). For the record, reason for the auto reject is probably author of the answer editing during the grace period.

Comment: Back on topic: maybe if the suggestion is rejected while it's still loading (same instant) there's some conflict or race condition leading to some bizarre error behind the scenes. Hard to reproduce!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I've just noticed, but too late to take a screenshot, an "expanded" variation over four lines of the normal message I see about what to do with the buttons. It is not always there. Perhaps a work-in-progress? The normal message being the one above the perfect hand-drawn circle in the question.

Comment: Scratch that. It looks like I accidently clicked on more for the first time ever.